# Redirecting logged in users to custom URL

Tags: redirect, login

If I'm going to use this code in my website

```
function redirect_logged_in_user() 
{
    if( is_user_logged_in () {
      wp_redirect('http://customurl');
    }
}

global $pagenow;
if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php')     
redirect_logged_in_user();
```

Should I be replacing the $pagenow url for every page I need this to happen? An example is that I have at least three pages which needs to redirect logged in users. Not only wp-login.php, but my membership login page and also register pages.

And, once I inserted it on my functions.php theme file, how can I make the is_user_logged_in work?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't replace the `$pagenow`, but would check it's value: `'wp-login.php' === $pagenow`.

I recommend using one of the `$_SERVER` values, or WordPress helper functions (ex: `is_page()`, [`is_login()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_login/)) on the `template_redirect` action hook.

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! is_login() ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_redirect( 'https://customurl' );
    exit;
} );
```

Comment: Oh by the way the $pagenow means that this code will check if it's on that wp-login.php page and then, if yes, it will put the functions to work? If I'm right, how can I replace the wp-login.php for like a normal URL?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to use `$pagenow`. The WordPress helper functions should be sufficient.